# Sum the values from two functions and add them together

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how best to ask this question, I'm new to Javascript and although I have got this far, I don't know how to shorten the code anymore than I have to make it easier to read so...

Here's my code:

```
var price;

function getInkPrice(arrayOfArrays){
    var inkName = 'Epson S60600';
    columnNumber = 7;
    arrayOfValues = arrayOfArrays.filter(function(r){return true;});
    var inkPrice = document.getElementById("ink-price");
    showPrice(inkPrice, arrayOfValues, columnNumber, inkName);
  }
  function getMileagePrice(arrayOfArrays){
    var mileageName = 'Mileage';
    columnNumber = 1;
    arrayOfValues = arrayOfArrays.filter(function(r){return true;});
    var mileagePrice = document.getElementById("mileage-price");
    showPrice(mileagePrice, arrayOfValues, columnNumber, mileageName);
  }

  function showPrice(el, arrayOfArrays, col, obj) {
    const results = arrayOfArrays.filter(r => r[0] === obj);
    const newResult = results [0][col].toFixed(2);
    el.textContent = newResult;
    price = newResult;
    combinePrice()
  }
  function combinePrice() {
    alert('your total price is ' + price + price);
  }
```

RESULTS
getInkPrice = 4.19
getMileagePrice = 0.55

Basically the getInkPrice() and getMileagePrice() setups the next function showPrice() to filter the results that I require.

The showPrice() function then filters the results and adds them to a div allowing me to display them in my html page.

Finally I created a global variable called 'price'. Once getMileagePrice() has finished, it calls the combinePrice() function which alerts the combined price (or it will do once I figure this out).

So, the combinePrice() function currently displays:

your total price is 4.194.19

That is wrong, it should display:

your total price is 4.74 (which is the 4.19 + 0.55).

I understand what part of the problem is but I can't figure to how I go about fixing it.

So my showPrice() function is doing the hard work in getting the values, it then stores that in the price variable. How does the price variable know what the value is seeing as both the getInkPrice() and getMileagePrice() are using it so it defaults to the first value.

So my global variable stores the 4.19 from the first function and not getting the value form the second function. Finally the 4.19 is not being classed as a number and therefor not adding them together. I could be wrong though.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: what are you filtering? it looks like copying. do you have html part and data (a tiny amount) as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `price = newResult;` will store a STRING in your price so `4.194.19` is `"4.19"+"4.19"`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. When you do `'your total price is ' + price + price`, the pluses are evaluated from left to right, so even the second + is actually string + rather than number +. You can solve this issue by doing `'your total price is ' + (price + price)`.
2. You have only one variable `price`, but you seem to need two separate ones, one for ink and the other one for mileage.

Comment: 1: Worked and allowed me to calculate the price. 2: How I do create the dynamic variable? I've tried creating a new variable in GetInkPrice and getMileagePrice with a unique name for each i.e. var one = inkName and var one = mileageName, (also making those variables global) I then pass that as a parameter called i.e abc. I thought I could then simply replace 'price = newResult;' with 'abc = newResult;' but all that does is creates a new variable called 'abc' where really I need the variable to be 'inkName = newResult;'

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1. Define `price` where you will sum results of your functions
2. Reset `price` value (to zero) each time before `getInkPrice` & `getMileagePrice` called
3. Add new result value to `price` inside of `showPrice` instead of redefining it
4. Get sum from `price` whereever you need

```js
var price; // [1]

price = 0; // [2] reset value somewhere before getInkPrice & getMileagePrice called

function getInkPrice(arrayOfArrays){
    var inkName = 'Epson S60600';
    columnNumber = 7;
    arrayOfValues = arrayOfArrays.filter(function(r){return true;});
    var inkPrice = document.getElementById("ink-price");
    showPrice(inkPrice, arrayOfValues, columnNumber, inkName);
}
function getMileagePrice(arrayOfArrays){
    var mileageName = 'Mileage';
    columnNumber = 1;
    arrayOfValues = arrayOfArrays.filter(function(r){return true;});
    var mileagePrice = document.getElementById("mileage-price");
    showPrice(mileagePrice, arrayOfValues, columnNumber, mileageName);
}

function showPrice(el, arrayOfArrays, col, obj) {
    const results = arrayOfArrays.filter(r => r[0] === obj);
    const newResult = results [0][col].toFixed(2);
    el.textContent = newResult;
    price += newResult; // [3] add to total price
    combinePrice();
}
function combinePrice() {
    alert('your total price is ' + price); // [4] get it when you wish 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that gave me 00.55

Comment: @Juan-man I believe it's happen because you reset `price` value in-between method calls. Can you clarify your question and add code snipper where you calls `getInkPrice` & `showPrice`?